# How to efficiently get breakpoints of piecewise functions

Tags: piecewise

**Setting**. Imagine that we have several arbitrary linear functions in 2D that can be changed manually (say, slopes are parameters). Their `Min` (or `Max`) gives a sort of piecewise continuous function.

**Example**. Let us take three functions.

```
try = {3 (1 - q), 2 (1 - q) + q, 1 + 1.5 q}
```

We can get a piecewise function as

```
Min[try]
```

It is fine to see it on the plot (for the domain `0<=q<=1`):

```
Plot[{try, Min[try]}, {q, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Problem**. Is there a simple way (or built-in functionality) to dynamically get coordinates (i.e., `q`'s) of all 'breaking' points of the piecewise function?

Comment: Is `Min[try] // PiecewiseExpand` (and manipulation of that result) what you're after?

Comment: @ciao. General and lapidary manipulation of that result would suffice.

Comment: `With[{rt = Rationalize[try]}, {#, Reduce[Min[rt] == #]} & /@ rt]` might also float your boat - in either case, you'll need to massage the results to pull out the items of interest....

Comment: @ciao, that is the 'massage' that puzzles me =) I see, that I have to collect all 'unique' bounds of intervals, but a bit confused how to do that efficiently. any ideas?

Comment: In example, one needs to transform @ciao result into something like `{q -> 1/2, q -> 2/5}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a kind of cheating way, which assumes that the function is differentiable except at the join-points and is not differentiable at the join-points:

```
Reduce[Not@Reduce[D[Min[try], q] \[Element] Reals, q], q] // ToRules // List
```

This works for your specified "linear functions" scenario; with your given function, it returns `{{q -> 2/5}, {q -> 1/2}}`.

Comment: Smart solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The undocumented function `` Internal`FromPiecewise `` seems to take a `Piecewise` function in the standard form returned by `PiecewiseExpand` and return a list consisting of a partition of the real numbers into intervals and a list of corresponding values.

```
try = {3 (1 - q), 2 (1 - q) + q, 1 + 1.5 q};
Internal`FromPiecewise@ PiecewiseExpand@ Min[try]
(*  {{0.4 <= q < 1/2, q >= 1/2, q < 0.4}, {2 - q, -3 (-1 + q), 1 + 1.5 q}}  *)
```

Since each break point occurs one at an equality (i.e. `<=` or `>=`), we can extract them and solve.  The function `ineqToEq` converts an inequality like those above to an equality or to `False` (which signifies no end point).

```
ineqToEq[ie_] := Replace[
  LogicalExpand@ ie /. Less | Greater -> (True &),
   {(GreaterEqual | LessEqual)[a_, b_] :> a == b, True -> False}
  ]
```

Applied to the OP's example:

```
Or @@ ineqToEq /@ First@ Internal`FromPiecewise@ PiecewiseExpand@ Min[try] // Solve
(*  {{q -> 0.4}, {q -> 1/2}}  *)
```

This following passes [Patrick Stevens's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/30771/patrick-stevens) clever `D` test, but this method finds the break point:

```
f = Piecewise[{{q^3, q < 0}}, q^2];
Or @@ ineqToEq /@ First@ Internal`FromPiecewise@ PiecewiseExpand@ f // Solve
(*  {{q -> 0}}  *)
```

---

**Another internal alternative**

There are many functions in *Mathematica* that process the discontinuities of a piecewise function.  You would think there would be an easy way to do it, but there doesn't seem to be one.  Well, here's a different function, again internal, undocumented, and subject to change, which is used by `NIntegrate`.  One advantage is that it handles `Min` with the user first converting it to a `Piecewise` function.

Here's how it works on the OP's function:

```
NIntegrate`PiecewiseNIntegrateMultipleRanges[
 Min[try], {{q, -Infinity, Infinity}}, {(* options *)}, {(* piecewise options *)}]
(*  {{2 - q, {q, 2/5, 1/2}}, {-3 (-1 + q), {q, 1/2, ∞}}, {1/2 (2 + 3 q), {q, -∞, 2/5}}} *)
```

General function and example:

```
pwBreaks[f_, x_] := 
 DeleteCases[Infinity | -Infinity]@*Union @@ 
  NIntegrate`PiecewiseNIntegrateMultipleRanges[
    f, {{x, -Infinity, Infinity}}, {}, {}][[All, 2, 2 ;; 3]]

pwBreaks[Min[try], q]
(*  {2/5, 1/2}  *)
```

Comment: I was waiting for somebody to bring up `FromPiecewise[]`… :)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. You'd think there would a common internal way to turn an inequality into an iterator `{x, a, b}` or return the end points -- I can't find one.  Dealing with the multiplicity of forms of inequalities is irritating.  Know of something?

Comment: None offhand; a function that converts inequalities to a standard form (e.g. entirely in terms of `<`/`<=`) would be very handy.

Comment: Now, *that*, I haven't tried using. Nice find!

Answer (score 5):

```
try = {3 (1 - q), 2 (1 - q) + q, 1 + 1.5 q} // Rationalize;

breaks = Cases[
   Last /@ (Min[try] // PiecewiseExpand)[[1]], _?NumericQ, {2}] // 
  Union
```

> {2/5, 1/2}

Comment: `Rule[q, #] & /@ breaks`. Very nice, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have to break the rule and say very impressive!