# Avoiding loops with breakpoints of a Piecewise function

Tags: piecewise, infinite-loop, envelope

I'm new to mathematica and I'm trying to avoid loops. The setting is the following: I have consumers with preferences (their Betas). Depending on the Beta consumers will have different preferences.

I take the upper envelope across the domain of Betas ([0,2]) and I get the breakpoints of the upper envelope.

`breaks=Cases[Last/@(InitialEnvelope[\[Beta]]//PiecewiseExpand)[[1]],_?NumericQ,{2}]//Union`

Which I took from: [How to efficiently get breakpoints of piecewise functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91190/how-to-efficiently-get-breakpoints-of-piecewise-functions).

[image: The dashed line is the maximum utility each customer can get]

Then I randomly extract a Beta from a distribution and compare it with the breakpoints of the upper envelope to check which is the maximal utility for that consumer.

Each time a new consumer arrives, she will change the upper envelope for the next one, and thus I need to update the breakpoints and compare them with the new Beta each time. Is there a way to update and collect the results for every step without a loop?

Comment: I think the short answer is *no*. The only way to avoid _updating_ after new information arrives (new _β_) is to have pre-calculated all the possible sequences of β's and perform a search.