# Adding a piece-wise function and its shifted version by list manipulations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a piecewise function represented by two lists,

```
x= {0, 30, 60, 120, 150, 180};
y= {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
```

and the plot of this function is

[image].

Now I would like to shift this function horizontally by an arbitrary angle and then add the shifted version to the original one. The original one can be thought of as periodic with a fundamental period of 180 degrees. For simplicity, shift it 15 degrees to the right and the sum should be something like this

[image]

By my previous convention, this result should be represented by `x1= {30, 45, 60, 75, 120, 135, 150, 165}, y1= {0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0}`. My question is, what can be one of the least complicated ways to obtain this result, particularly the vertical value list `y1` above, by using list manipulations?

Comment: Although not stated the same way this is related to an old Question of mine from Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5784046/618728  Also somewhat related: [(30055)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30055/121), [(30438)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30438/121), [(71426)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71426/121)

Answer (score 7):

```
x = {0, 30, 60, 120, 150, 180};
y = {0, 1, 0, -1, 0};

f[z_] := Piecewise @ Transpose @ {y, Less @@@ Insert[z, 2] /@ Partition[x, 2, 1]}
f[z]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[z], {z, 0, 180}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

```
Plot[f[z] + f[z - 15], {z, 0, 180}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

---

```
g[z_] := f[z] + f[z - 15]

PiecewiseExpand @ g[z]
```

[image]

Building on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91200/22013):

```
args = Join[{0, 180}, 
    z /. (Reduce[Not@Reduce[D[g[z], z] ∈ Reals, z], z] // 
        ToRules // List)] // Sort // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {0, 30, 45, 60, 75, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180}

```
g[#] & /@ (RandomReal[#] & /@ Partition[args, 2, 1])
```

> {0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0}

---

There's also an undocumented function converting `Piecewise` to `UnitStep` ([thanks to xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133494/22013)):

```
Simplify`PWToUnitStep @ g[z]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm interesting about how do you dig to get that?

Comment: Yep,I have.Thanks. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `UnitBox`, e.g.

```
f[x_] := UnitBox[(x - 30)/30 - 1/2] - UnitBox[(x - 120)/30 - 1/2]
Plot[f[x] + f[x - 15], {x, 0, 200}]
```

[image]

**Update**

I add this to address Mr. Wizard's comment. There are many ways and probably better but to get corners:

```
g[x_] := f[x] + f[x - 15]
pts = {u, 
    g[u]} /. {ToRules@Reduce[Not[FunctionDomain[D[g[u], u], u]], u]};
{xs, ys} = Transpose[pts]
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 200}, 
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[Thread[{xs, 0}]]}, 
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

**Correction**

To deal with the dfference between the definition of `UnitBox` and the desired outcome a small offset to get what is aimed for:

```
ptscorr = {u, 
   g[u - 0.01]} /. {ToRules@
    Reduce[Not[FunctionDomain[D[g[u], u], u]], u]};
{xscorr, yscorr} = Transpose[ptscorr]
```

yields:

```
{30, 45, 60, 75, 120, 135, 150, 165}, {0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1}}
```

Comment: How would you convert the `UnitBox` expression into the `x1`/`y1` output shown?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have updated to address your comment ( I hope). It could be done a few ways but something different.  [This spider](http://i.imgur.com/9fhGA4X.jpg) built an elaborate web in my garden and made me think of you.  I hope you pass "happy holidays". On a selfish note: I have always wanted to post on the "i've passed 5000" but have never found an interesting enough number and am too inept to game. 40000 was a nice milestone in an otherwise terrible year :)

Comment: You already had my vote but now the answer is even better.  I am happy that a wonder of nature makes you think of me. I am not happy to hear that you have had a terrible year.  I hope that things have turned around now, whatever the circumstance.