# How to get edge values of the piecewise function if it has discontinuties

Tags: piecewise

```
Qplot = Piecewise[{{Ray, h <= c/3}, 
 {Ray-P, c/3 <= h <=c},
 {Ray-P-q*(h-c) + X1, c <= h <= c+b},
 {Ray-P-q*b + X1 + X2, c+b <= h <= c+b+a}}]
```

As can be seen on the plot, this function has discontinuities on certain points (like c/3, c, etc). I need to get values on both edges of those discontinuities. Using

```
Qplot /. {{h->c/3},{h->c}}
```

and a list of rules for that gives only one edge. I feel like this has something to do with correctly setting the piecewise function.
Seems like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91190/how-to-efficiently-get-breakpoints-of-piecewise-functions) gives `h` in my scenario
[image: Plot]

Comment: Can you make some assumptions on the parameters `a`, `b`, etc.? For example, is `c > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assumptions = {a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && Element[{a, b, c}, Reals]};

lims = Thread[h -> Qplot[[1, All, 2]][[All, -1]]];
{#, limits = Function[x, Limit[Qplot, #, Assumptions -> assumptions, 
        Direction -> x]] /@ {1, -1}, limits[[2]] - limits[[1]]} & /@ lims // 
 Grid[{{"breakpoints", "{left values, right values}", "difference"}, ## & @@ #}, 
  Dividers -> All] &
```

> [image]

Under the same assumptions:

```
values = Append[Qplot[[1, All, 1]], Qplot[[-1]]];
breakpoints = Qplot[[1, ;; , 2]][[All, -1]];
{h, #, #[[2]] - #[[1]]} /. #2 & @@@ 
  Thread[{Partition[values, 2, 1], Thread[h -> breakpoints]}] // 
 Grid[{{"breakpoints", "{left values, right values}", "difference"}, ## & @@ #}, 
   Dividers -> All] &
```

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like using

```
Limit[Qplot, {{h->c/3},{h->c},{h->c+b}, {h->c+b+a}}, Direction->1]
Limit[Qplot, {{h->c/3},{h->c},{h->c+b}, {h->c+b+a}}, Direction->-1]
```

works somewhat okay, though a bit ugly, wonder if there are more elegant ways.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know a few things about the parameters. Specifically, I use

```
$Assumptions = Thread[{a, b, c, Ray, P, q, X1, X2} > 0]
(* {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0, Ray > 0, P > 0, q > 0, X1 > 0, X2 > 0} *)
```

Then you can get all discontinuities with

```
breakpoints = Flatten[
  Solve[# == 0, h] & /@ 
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Cases[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[Qplot], UnitStep[arg_] :> arg, Infinity]
  ]
(* {h -> c/3, h -> c, h -> b + c, h -> a + b + c} *)
```

(I guess there is a more elegant way, but it works) and the left/right limits at each point in symbolic form:

```
Table[
   Most@Pick[
     Sequence@@Reverse[Simplify[Internal`FromPiecewise[Qplot] /. bp]]
   ],
   {bp, breakpoints}
]
(* {{Ray, -P + Ray}, {-P + Ray, -P + Ray + X1}, {-P - b q + Ray + 
   X1, -P - b q + Ray + X1 + X2}, {-P - b q + Ray + X1 + X2}} *)
```

You can safely ignore the red mark the front end will show you at the end of the argument of `Pick`, as `Pick` expects two arguments. We actually provide two arguments using `Sequence@@`.

Here I use the undocumented function `` Internal`FromPiecewise `` which does this:

```
Internal`FromPiecewise[Qplot]
(* {{h <= c/3, c/3 <= h <= c, c <= h <= b + c, b + c <= h <= a + b + c, 
  True}, {Ray, -P + Ray, -P - (-c + h) q + Ray + X1, -P - b q + Ray + 
   X1 + X2, 0}} *)
```